# Proxy Settings at Android Studio first time startup

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy

I am new to Android Studio and I am having this proxy settings issue. I just installed the Android Studio and loaded an android project and came to see this dialog. I dont know anything about proxy and stuff, so please help me out. Thank you.
[image: Proxy Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

This is a proxy settings dialog that takes permission from the user to access HTTP Protocols and Internet which is used to download all the dependencies that you use in your project from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you do not have to (like your country in the US sanction etc..) use a proxy.
Uncheck "Enable HTTPS Proxy".
Check "Do n to show this dialog in the future".
Click on "Yes".